# Dell XPS M1330 with failed Nvidia graphics card, looking for motherboard replacement

Tags: laptop, dell-xps

I have a Dell XPS M1330, it is not working any more due to graphics card issues. When I called Dell support they said that my machine is out of warranty so I need to pay to fix it!

I heard that such issues can be caused by a defective Nvidia chip. If is it true, does it means that I can get it fixed for free? If yes, how I can know that it is the Nvidia chip issue?

As to the other part of my question, I went to eBay and looked for a motherboard replacement, but I saw that there are many revisions! Mine is REV A04. Also, there is a confusing thing, there are motherboards with D057F, P083J, GM848, .... what is all this about?

Comment: A04 looks more like a BIOS revision than a motherboard one, can you confirm this.

Comment: hmmm, i think that too, how I can know the MB revision or type?

Comment: The only thing you can do is open it up and check on the motherboard itself, the BIOS would usually state the motherboard revision but you can't access it.

Comment: you mean open it and look inside? ok I may do that, but then what?

Comment: Well that's the only way for you to actually know what MB it is to determine compatibility for your laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, I too just experienced this issue. I have been using my M1330 for almost three years with no problem until now. My laptop is long past warranty (expired July 2009) so the extended warranty on this issue is also dead by now. For more information, you can try here:

> http://en.community.dell.com/dell-blogs/direct2dell/b/direct2dell/archive/2008/09/12/nvidia-gpu-update-limited-warranty-enhancement-details.aspx

Unfortunately, I think at this point the only way to remedy the problem would be to replace the motherboard as you have suggested but that doesn't come cheap. I'm likely going to buy a new machine...

Comment: I have the same problem. Has anyone come up with some creative uses for the remainig iron? Seems such a waste to let a perfectly good laptop go to waste, just beacuse it can't display what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

The nVidia laptop settlement from the class action suit is [closed and no longer accepting claims](http://www.nvidiasettlement.com/index.html).  However, your specific model of laptop was only subject to repair or replacement if it was purchased between [March 2007 and September 30, 2008](http://www.nvidiasettlement.com/pdfs/NVF_NOT.pdf) (PDF, see page 3).

The numbers you're seeing are Dell part numbers.  You would likely need to open the case and examine the system board for the correct part number.